# Position something in Tikz beamer relative to size of figure in node

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

I am trying to position another figure or text on the side of figure that I include in a node within a `tikzpicture` environment. Basically I would like the following:

```
    -------------------
    |                 |
   *|      (node)     |
    |                 |
    -------------------
```

where the box denotes the whole size of the figure that in my tikzpicture I include for example, by

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

...

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=east,xshift=1cm,yshift=0.5cm] (fig) at (current page.east) {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{myfig.png}};
%% Ideally I would do:
\node[left=0cm of fig] {*};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but it actually produces something like:

```
    -------------------
    |                 |
    |                 |  *(current page.east)
    |                 |
    -------------------
```

meaning, to me, that `left` option is w.r.t. to the `current page.east` and not to the actual extension of the node (which is my figure in this case). How can I solve this?

Comment: See `pgfmanual sec 17.13.2 Referencing the Current Page Node – Absolute Positioning`: by giving the `remember picture` and the `overlay` options to a picture, you can position nodes absolutely on a page.

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck Sorry but I don't see how this reference is pertinent. The absolute positioning here is fine. It is the problem that I need to position my * on the edge of the figure, and I do not know how to have info on the figure size...

Comment: Please provide a complete small document (MWE), which reproduce your problem (and on this way clarify, what is the problem).

Answer (score 0):

- Please give complete minimal working example.
- Referencing the `current page` node need set `remember picture, overlay` option, otherwise the picture with be inserted right here
- Node has `inner sep`, that's why your text is not at the right place.

The code below should work fine:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
\node[anchor=east, draw, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=3cm, minimum width=3cm]
  (fig) at (current page.east) {fig};
\node at (fig.west) {*};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]